# symfony 3 unexpected result with master request on service

Tags: php, symfony, session, request

I am setting up a service to run BEFORE the controller to initialize some server variables.

This service should only run if it is the master request, which I believe should be only one for a page request.

So far I managed to get it running, but it does not seem to give the expected result. It seems to be running a couple of times if it is the master request and only once otherwise. Of course, I may just be misreading this.

In the code below the line below should identify the master request:

> ($this->stack->getParentRequest() == null)

Then the session['page_ct'] below should be increased by 1 for every new page, but it increases by 2. It does increase by only 1 if I change the code to != null.

> ($this->session->has('page_ct') ? $this->session->set('page_ct', $this->session->get('page_ct') + 1 ): $this->session->set('page_ct', 1 ));

This is the set up:

app/config/services.yml

```
services:
app.initializer_listener:
  class: AppBundle\EventListener\InitializerListener
  arguments: ['@session','@request_stack']
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: InitializerAction }
```

and the initializer ( skeleton code only );

/src/AppBundle/EventListener/InitializerListener.php

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class InitializerListener
{
private $session;
private $event;
private $stack;

public function __construct(Session $session, RequestStack $requestStack )
{
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->stack = $requestStack;
}

public function InitializerAction(){
    if ($this->stack->getParentRequest() == null) { ********
        $this->sessionInit();
    }
}

private function sessionInit ()
{
    $this->session->set('active', time() );
    ($this->session->has('page_ct') ? $this->session->set('page_ct', $this->session->get('page_ct') + 1 ): $this->session->set('page_ct', 1 ));     
}


}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @hakre. I will repeat this for your sake: Then the session['page_ct'] below should be increased by 1 for every new page, but it increases by 2. It does increase by only 1 if I change the code to != null.

Comment: That is not a question, that is a description. What is your question? How to find out that a request is a master request? Or: Is Does the the Master reqeust construct all properties that allow to decide on a single operation per request?

Comment: @hakre, You seem to be very keen on semantics. So read the title of the question: unexpected result. Try to be helpful instead.  I will stop this exchange here. Thanks.

Comment: And is it unexpected to you to not use getRequestType()  to check for the master request or is that expected? And no need to be offended, I'm just asking. That's what you do as well.

Comment: Do not inject the request or session.  Instead the request is passed as part of the event.  See the docs for examples.

Comment: Thanks, @Cerad. I just tried that, obtaining session as $this->session = $requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getSession();. But that does not solve the problem. I am still getting +2 for each page load, when I should only get +1 on my session('page_ct').

Comment: Don't use request stack at all in a controller listener.  Use the passed request and test it for being the master.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#request-events-checking-types

Comment: @Cerad, Before the above code I had already tried the info you linked to. It does not seem to have a service name for GetResponseEvent or, if I omit the argument on services.yml, would give the error : ::onKernelRequest() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent given. This even if I take out the use for FilterControllerEvent

Comment: You seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding the use of listeners.  Try getting the one in the docs working and then adjusting it.  Makes no sense to call some sort of initialize thing.

Comment: Instead of your initializer method you should have a onController(FilterControllerEvent $event)

Comment: @Cerad, not sure I am misunderstanding the use of listeners. Their purpose is to link code to an event and that's exactly what I am trying to do. There is code that needs to be run before the controllers and should not be placed in the controllers themselves otherwise I would repeat code, which one should avoid to do. Basically the method in question set basic session and cookies variables. As per the InitializerListener.php script, it uses the same setup as the example code from Symfony docs. Something is amiss, of course.

Comment: @Cerad, used the FilterControllerEvent and it worked, as did my code above. Still it adds +2 to session('page_ct') for each page load.

Comment: Update the question with your actual code.  I suspect you are redirecting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues here.

First, please try testing your code in **prod** environment. I think your listener is called two times because of running the code in **dev** environment with an active Web Debug Toolbar (WDT). The toolbar causes the second valid master request.

I highly recommend reading the [relevant documentation about controller events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html). Your `InitializerAction()` is lacking the passed event, so I guess you missed that part. There is no reason to inject the request stack into the listener. You have access to the request object from the `$event` via `$event->getRequest()`. That is what @Cerad was talking about.

There are several ways to exclude the WDT request and I am not sure if my approach is the best, but you could check for the route and exclude it:

```
public function InitializerAction(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $route = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');
    if ($event->isMasterRequest() && '_wdt' !== $route) {
        $this->sessionInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lordrhodos. The issue was really the WDT. I tried it on prod but also with your code above and it works as expected. In fact both codes, ie, my original above and using FilterControllerEvent, accomplish the task once one excludes the additional WDT's master request, which I did know exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to include the final code for the benefit of others, after @Cerad comments and @lordrhodos input.

app/config/services.yml

```
services:
app.initializer_listener:
  class: AppBundle\EventListener\InitializerListener
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelRequest }
```

/src/AppBundle/EventListener/InitializerListener.php

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;


use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;


class InitializerListener
{

public $event;

public function onKernelRequest( FilterControllerEvent  $event )
{
        $route = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');
        if ($event->isMasterRequest() && '_wdt' !== $route ) {
            $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
            $this->sessionInit($session);
        }
}

private function sessionInit($session)
{
    $session->set('active', time() );
    $session->has('page_ct') ? $session->set('page_ct', $session->get('page_ct') + 1 ): $session->set('page_ct', 1 );
}
}
```