# Symfony 3.4 event listener for routing

Tags: symfony, routes, listener, symfony-3.4

Im trying to display a flashbag on every page under certain conditions (loged in user, etc...), but im not sure how to use the right event listener, i think maybe I need some routing event listener for that...

Anyway, I tried with kernel.controller but in several pages there are more than 1 controller rendering content so **I get duplicate flashbags** in those pages. Thats why I think I need to use routes instead of controllers.

This is my code so far, I avoided conditions for now only to testing if its working (so it shows in any page always):

**services.yml:**

```
Appbundle\EventListener\ChapterFlashbagListener:
  arguments: [ '@session','@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@security.token_storage', '@translator' ]
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event:  kernel.controller, method: preExecute }
```

**ChapterFlashbagListener:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class ChapterFlashbagListener
{
  private $session;
  private $em;
  private $tokenStorage;
  protected $translator;

  public function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $em, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, TranslatorInterface $translator)
  {
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    $this->translator = $translator;
  }
  /**
  * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
  */
  public function preExecute(FilterControllerEvent $event)
  {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $m = $this->translator->trans('message'); 
    $session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', $m);
  }
}
```

Additional info: The project is a backend with Sonata if that info helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check wether the request is the **master request** to avoid those dublicate messages.

This can be done as follows:

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

 if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST) {
     return;
 }

 $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', $warning);
```

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you! One more thing for the record... I was on development environment so it seems the toolbar does another master request and still get 2 flashbags, I turned toolbar to false in config_dev.yml to get only one flashbag. In prod env should work fine. Found the answer to that issue on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606796/symfony-3-unexpected-result-with-master-request-on-service

Comment: You could also just use `$event->isMasterRequest()` .. does the same